# After theano installation with pipenv no module theano exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to install theano in python 3.5.2 with pipenv.After the installation Successfully built theano
Installing collected packages: theano
Successfully installed theano-1.0.1

```
Adding theano to Pipfile's [packages]…
Pipfile.lock (4eb1d4) out of date, updating to (3c6e07)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (3c6e07)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (3c6e07)…
  ================================ 26/26 - 00:00:44
To activate this project's virtualenv, run the following:
 $ pipenv shell
```

I tried to run a simple import theano but the windows cmd display the following

```
C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\pipenvtests>C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pipenv.exe run C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\pipenvtests\kr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\pipenvtests\kr.py", line 1, in <module>
    import theano
ImportError: No module named 'theano'
```

Do anyone know why this happens.I google it but i did not find enough information about pipenv.
Thanks